# XPath select following until some condition?

Tags: scrapy, xpath-2.0

I'm having a trouble selecting product from following node. Here's the html:

```
 <div>
      <p>Order ID 1</p>
      <p style="display:none"></p>
      <p>product 1</p>

      <p>Order ID 2</p>
      <p style="display:none"></p>
      <p>product 1</p>
      <p>product 2</p>
      
      <p>Order ID 3</p>
      <p style="display:none"></p>
      <p>product 1</p>
      <p>product 2</p>
    
      <p>Order ID 4</p>
      <p style="display:none"></p>
      <p>product 1</p>
      <p>product 2</p>
      <p>product 3</p>
     
      <p>Order ID 5</p>
      <p style="display:none"></p>
      <p>product 1</p>  
      
    </div>
```

I selected Order ID with following code:

```
//div/p[@style="display:none"]/preceding-sibling::p[1]
```

Is there any way to select product? code I tried :

```
//div/p[@style="display:none"]/following::p[not(@style="display:none" )]
```

result :

```
<p>product 1</p>
<p>Order ID 2</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>Order ID 3</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>Order ID 4</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>product 3</p>
<p>Order ID 5</p>
<p>product 1</p>
```

How to deselect order ID

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `text()` content, as follow:

`//div/p[contains(text(), 'product')]/text()`

or

`//div/p[not(contains(text(), 'Order'))]/text()`

Using Scrapy in python the output using `extract()` function is:

`['product 1', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', 'product 1']`

Answer (score 1):

## **I. Use**:

```
/div/p[@style='display:none']
      /following-sibling::p[not(@style)]
                             [not(following-sibling::p[1][@style='display:none'])]
```

## **II. Explanation**

In simple words this XPath expression instructs the XPath engine to do the following:

*Get all following siblings of all **`p`** elements that are children of the top element **`div`** and have a **`style`** attribute with value the string **`"display:none"`**, such that (these following siblings) don't have a **`style`** attribute themselves, and are not an immediate preceding sibling of a **`p`** element that has a **`style`** attribute with value the string **`"display:none"`***

## **III. XSLT - based verification:**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/div/p[@style='display:none']
            /following-sibling::p[not(@style)]
                                   [not(following-sibling::p[1][@style='display:none'])]
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```xml
<div>
    <p>Order ID 1</p>
    <p style="display:none"></p>
    <p>product 1</p>
    <p>Order ID 2</p>
    <p style="display:none"></p>
    <p>product 1</p>
    <p>product 2</p>
    <p>Order ID 3</p>
    <p style="display:none"></p>
    <p>product 1</p>
    <p>product 2</p>
    <p>Order ID 4</p>
    <p style="display:none"></p>
    <p>product 1</p>
    <p>product 2</p>
    <p>product 3</p>
    <p>Order ID 5</p>
    <p style="display:none"></p>
    <p>product 1</p>
</div>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and its (wanted, correct) result  is copied to the output**:

```xml
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>product 1</p>
<p>product 2</p>
<p>product 3</p>
<p>product 1</p>
```

Here is a screenshot of evaluating this XPath expression with the XPath Visualizer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `p` tags that their following sibling doesn't have that style (this won't apply to `Order ID i`).

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: from scrapy import Selector

In [2]: html=""" <div>
   ...:       <p>Order ID 1</p>
   ...:       <p style="display:none"></p>
   ...:       <p>product 1</p>
   ...: 
   ...:       <p>Order ID 2</p>
   ...:       <p style="display:none"></p>
   ...:       <p>product 1</p>
   ...:       <p>product 2</p>
   ...:       
   ...:       <p>Order ID 3</p>
   ...:       <p style="display:none"></p>
   ...:       <p>product 1</p>
   ...:       <p>product 2</p>
   ...:     
   ...:       <p>Order ID 4</p>
   ...:       <p style="display:none"></p>
   ...:       <p>product 1</p>
   ...:       <p>product 2</p>
   ...:       <p>product 3</p>
   ...:      
   ...:       <p>Order ID 5</p>
   ...:       <p style="display:none"></p>
   ...:       <p>product 1</p>  
   ...:       
   ...:     </div>"""

In [3]: sel = Selector(text=html)

In [4]: sel.xpath('//div/p[@style="display:none"]/following::p[not(following::p[1][@style="display:none"])]/text()').ge
   ...: tall()
Out[4]:
['product 1',
 'product 1',
 'product 2',
 'product 1',
 'product 2',
 'product 1',
 'product 2',
 'product 3',
 'product 1']
```